# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.hasread.userId')

Tags: react-native

I have seen similar topics, but I haven't been able to figure out why this issue is still showing for me.
Let me explain.

In react native I show data in a list. Which works fine, but when I try to look for a specific data: data.hasread.userId, I get the famous red error screen, saying:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.hasread.userId')
```

So in my code I try to ignore data that is undefined and only get those who aren't.

```
const dataUserId = typeof data.hasread.userId !== "undefined" && data.hasread.userId;
```

For one data I get true (as it contains the userId), but anything else shows the typeError.
It shouldn't.

Any idea why?

BTW, this is how that hasread structure is looking (firestore data):

```
hasread
    userId -> uid
```

Comment: provide code so that it is easy to identify what is the actual problem

Comment: There is not much to provide, since that line is causing it. As I comment it out, the issue is gone.

Comment: but providing minimal code will give us more insight to help you out

Answer (score 0):

I might have found the solution, although not sure if it is the best, but as least it seems to work.

I changed:

```
const dataUserId = typeof data.hasread.userId !== "undefined" && data.hasread.userId;
```

To:

```
const dataUserId = data.hasread && typeof data.hasread.userId !== "undefined" && data.hasread.userId;
```

And now the error isn't showing